# Aggregating value over multi-level hierarchy while exculding members

Tags: ssas, mdx, hierarchy

I have a cube that contains a multi level manager hierarchy as well as units of work that have been completed over a time dimension. Lets assume this is the data I'm working with:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNP4L.png

What I'm trying to do via MDX is focus on a specific level, (Level 1, John Smith) and remove individuals (both end users and managers) from the hierarchy and properly rollup the values.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xW5CF.png

As  you can see from the above image, we've removed Lisa Rice and Morgan Richardson's entire team.  The expected results would be two columns, Full Name and Work Units.

The query that I've put together so far looks like this:

```
WITH SET [MyCustomSet] AS EXCEPT(
    DESCENDANTS([HR].[Mgr Hierarchy].&[JSMITH],, SELF_AND_AFTER), 
    {DESCENDANTS([HR].[Mgr Hierarchy].&[MRICHARDSON],,SELF_AND_AFTER), DESCENDANTS([HR].[Mgr Hierarchy].&[LRICE],,SELF_AND_AFTER)}
)
MEMBER [Measures].[MyMeasure] AS Aggregate([MyCustomSet], [Measures].[#Work Units])
SELECT {
    [Measures].[MyMeasure]
} ON COLUMNS, 
NON EMPTY {
    [MyCustomSet]
} ON ROWS
FROM [MyCube]
```

But this returns a list of the members I need but the aggregated value for every single member is the total for all members.  When I remove the calculated measure and just use the `[Measures].[#Work Units]` the values represent the total rollup values without the members removed however the members are not present in the column.

The eventual home for this data will be in a SSRS table setup with a recursive parent relationship to display the hierarchy correctly.

Can anyone lend a hand or point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: Ended up working it out on my own

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to change your `Aggregate()` to be the aggregation below each member, and not for the entire `[MyCustomSet]`. Something like:

```
MEMBER [Measures].[MyMeasure] AS 
    Aggregate([HR].[Mgr Hierarchy].CurrentMember, [Measures].[#Work Units])
```

**Edit**: If you are looking for the aggregation to change at each parent level, maybe you should be looking at using a subselect.

```
SELECT 
    [Measures].[#Work Units] ON COLUMNS, 
    NON EMPTY [HR].[Mgr Hierarchy].Members ON ROWS
FROM (
    SELECT EXCEPT(
        DESCENDANTS([HR].[Mgr Hierarchy].&[JSMITH],, SELF_AND_AFTER), 
        {DESCENDANTS([HR].[Mgr Hierarchy].&[MRICHARDSON],,SELF_AND_AFTER), DESCENDANTS([HR].[Mgr Hierarchy].&[LRICE],,SELF_AND_AFTER)}
        ON COLUMNS
    FROM [MyCube]
)
```

Comment: Changing this aggregates the total number of work items for a set that still includes the members I want to exclude.  Thats why the custom set has to be included in this calculation.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misunderstood your question. So you want a custom set, and you want the totals at each level to be consistent with the members your kept or removed from the custom set? Have you tried a subselect?

Comment: Ah, I had completely forgotten about sub queries (still fairly new to MDX).  So I've modified the query and I've confirmed the the sub query is returning the correct members but in the overall query the excluded members are still included.  Any thoughts?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: It might depend on your hierarchy, and exactly what you're selecting or excluding. Keep in mind that the subselect/subcube will include all ascendants and descendants of any member that you select -- you're telling the cube which branches of the hierarchy to keep, not giving a simple list of single members. So if your subselect includes a member at/near the top of the hierarchy, you'll still get all of its children; if your subselect specifies only some children, you'll get their parents/ascendants back to the root of the hierarchy but not their "uncles".

Comment: Thanks finango, thats a concept I didn't grasp in relation to subqueries, its a bummer that MDX doesn't allow picking out specific members in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with a [sub-query](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/SubQueries.html); this way you'll be able to select only the [HR] members you want to keep and using VISUAL (default behavior) vs NON VISUAL mode you'll get the aggregated values either for the actual selected members or for all the members in the dimension:

```
WITH SET [MyCustomSet] AS EXCEPT(
    DESCENDANTS([HR].[Mgr Hierarchy].&[JSMITH],, SELF_AND_AFTER), 
    {DESCENDANTS([HR].[Mgr Hierarchy].&[MRICHARDSON],,SELF_AND_AFTER), DESCENDANTS([HR].[Mgr Hierarchy].&[LRICE],,SELF_AND_AFTER)}
)

SELECT
    [Measures].[#Work Units] ON 0, NON EMPTY [MyCustomSet] ON 1
FROM ( select [MyCustomSet] on 0 from [MyCube] )
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, it looks like a subquery may be the path (as findango also suggested) but the except statement doesn't seem to be filtering out the members I need excluded.  Also, after trying your version of the query, it appears you can't use sets named in the outside query in the sub query.  Thanks again for your input.